# Using typedef with an instance declaration. Wiki error?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, wiki

In accordance to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29) Wiki page, it is possible to write the following structure:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int integer;
} my_struct_t instance;
```

K&R do not mention this in "C Proglamming Language".
Compiler also returns error during the compilation:

> error: expected `=`, `,`, `;`, `asm`, or `__attribute__` before `instance`

Is it a Wiki error or I do something stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the page. You can *either* make a `typedef`, *or* define an instance of the structure, but not both.

It might be clearer if you read the whole page and not only syntax block at the top.

Comment: The syntax they propose is still wrong - they tried to be too concise by adding the concept of `typedef` into a struct declaration syntax, as well as instantiation.

Comment: The syntax block is totally confusing.

Comment: @Alex I agree that it's confusing, because they try to show all possible permutations of `struct` in one go. They should have two blocks, one for normal `struct` definitions and one for `typedef` definitions.